# Coverting Java project to a Maven project - can not find or load the main class

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have an old Java 1.8 project that I converted to Maven project in Eclipse.

After **mvn eclipse:eclipse**, the project structure changes so that Eclipse does not show packages, but a directories-like-structure. Now when I try to "Run as Java Application", Eclipse gives me a list of some weird classes to run - none of which are the Main class.

Now, if I **run mvn eclipse:clean**, the directory structure goes back to Package-like-view and I can choose the main class when I run the project as a Java Application, but I still get the main class not found along with error:

"Description Resource Path Location Type
The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for java.lang.Object. Fix the build path then try building this project"

The build path should be okay after the mvn eclipse:eclipse. At least all the libraries are there and also jdk 1.8 library.

**Maybe I am missing something, some kinda dependency missing from pom?**

I am using Java version 1.8

My pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>myJavaApplication</groupId>
    <artifactId>myJavaApplication</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>myJavaApplication</name>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>my.java.application.main.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>itext</groupId>
            <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core-lgpl</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: probably you should add the java 1.8 library to the Java Build Path of your project , right click on the project , properties , java build path , libraries , Add library, JRE System library , and select your jdk directory

Comment: @OussamaZAGHDOUD jdk 1.8 library is already there

Comment: the maven-eclipse plugin is deprecated for a long time as the integration has improved a lot. In fact, using the plugin probably works counter productive. I suggest to remove the project from eclipse, remove all eclipse related files and import it again as Maven project.